# After NSChineseCalendar Deprecated in iOS 8.0, How can I get ChineseCalendar now?

Tags: objective-c, nscalendar, nslocale

After NSChineseCalendar Deprecated in iOS 8.0, How can I get ChineseCalendar now?

in the Documentation

- NSChineseCalendar

Identifier for the Chinese calendar.

Available in iOS 2.0 and later.

Deprecated in iOS 8.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to the declaration of the key in `NSLocale.h` you will see this...

`FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString * const NSChineseCalendar NS_CALENDAR_DEPRECATED(10_4, 10_9, 2_0, 7_0, "Use NSCalendarIdentifierChinese instead");`

> Use NSCalendarIdentifierChinese instead

When in doubt, read the documentation!